# Problem with Font Awesome icons on Magento 2

Tags: magento, font-awesome, magento2

I'm trying to add Font Awesome icons in Magento 2 (2.4.3), but I have a problem: HTML tags are not replaced by the svg icon.
The script loads, the HTML tag is rendered on the page, but it is not working.
I tested the same code in another project (HTML only) and it works.
I think it's a problem working with Magento.

Comment: Post example code

Comment: This is the template file:


`<div>
    <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=5518996628407" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
        <i class="whatsapp"></i> (18) 99662-8407   
    </a>
    <a href="mailto:vendas@showglassportas.com.br">
        <span class="fa-regular fa-envelope"></span> vendas@showglassportas.com.br
    </a>
</div>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/fb151ae045.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

I put the script in the template just for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a custom script to load the SVG files from my own server.